# Why isn't SQLAlchemy enforcing foreign key constraints with SQLite?

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, foreign-keys

I'm misunderstanding something about SqlAlchemy ForeignKey constraints. My understanding is that the insertion of `B` below should raise a ForeignKeyConstraint exception because there's no `A` with `"my_a"` as its name. Isn't that what a ForeignKey constraint does? Require the existence of the value in the table column mapped by the constraint when the constrained table is updated?

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, create_engine, ForeignKey, Integer, VARCHAR
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()


class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_A'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(VARCHAR(32))


class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'table_B'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    a_name = Column(VARCHAR(32), ForeignKey('table_A.name'), nullable=False)


engine = create_engine('sqlite:////tmp/AB.db.foo')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

Session = sessionmaker()
Session.configure(bind=engine)

b = B(a_name="my_a")

session = Session()
session.add(b)
session.commit()
session.close()
```

Comment: By default, SQLite does not enforce foreign keys. SQLAlchemy-specific details [here](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support).

Comment: Ahh, thanks Gord, that was it. If you make this an answer instead of a comment I'll accept and upvote. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite – even modern versions – does not enforce foreign keys by default.

> Assuming the [SQLite] library is compiled with foreign key constraints enabled, it must still be enabled by the application at runtime, using the PRAGMA foreign_keys command.

[SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html)

[SQLAlchemy documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support)