# SQLAlchemy delete doesn`t cascade SQLite

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy, one-to-many

I have `user` model and `computers` model.

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy import Column
from sqlalchemy import Integer
from sqlalchemy import ForeignKey
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped
from sqlalchemy.orm import mapped_column


engine = create_engine(
    "sqlite:///./database.db",
    echo=True,
)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
Base = declarative_base()

class UserOrm(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True, default="")
    age: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(nullable=True, default=0)
    computers = relationship(
        "ComputerOrm",
        back_populates="host",
        cascade="all, delete",
        passive_deletes=True,
    )


class ComputerOrm(Base):
    __tablename__ = "computers"

    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name: Mapped[str]
    host_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id", ondelete="CASCADE"), index=True, nullable=False)
    host = relationship(UserOrm, back_populates="computers")

Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

If I execute the code:

```py
with Session() as session:
    session.query(UserOrm).filter_by(id=some_id).delete()
    session.commit()
```

user deleted, but user`s computers does not delete.

SQLAlchemy echo:

```
2023-12-23 17:12:21,384 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-12-23 17:12:21,390 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine DELETE FROM users WHERE users.id = ?
2023-12-23 17:12:21,392 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00172s] (1,)
```

If I exec SQL script in `DB Browser for SQLite` all works. User and user`s computers deleted.

```
DELETE FROM users WHERE users.id = some_id;
```

SQL Create table scripts, generated by SQLAlchemy:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR, 
    age INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE computers (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
    host_id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(host_id) REFERENCES users (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

How fix problem?

```bash
$ pip show sqlalchemy
Name: SQLAlchemy
Version: 2.0.23
...
```

python 3.12.1

SQLite 3.35.5

Windows 10 Pro 22H2 64-bit

## What have I done

Check create table scripts.

Try execute SQL script from `SQLAlchemy` echo to `DB Browser for SQLite`.

Try more solution for my problem.

Try `session.delete(user_orm)`.

Try more params combinations for relationship/ForeignKey.

https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/cascades.html#using-foreign-key-on-delete-cascade-with-orm-relationships

Comment: just a quick mention.  if you are importing that many functions from a module, it would save code lines and add clarity to use an alias.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64812766/2144390

Comment: Could you check, if your PRAGMA foreign_keys is enabled?
sql_key = """PRAGMA foreign_keys;"""
print(next(cur.execute(sql_key))) , IF you get 0 means disabled, 1 means enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look on the [SQLAlchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/sqlite.html) documentation, how to switch on foreign_keys:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine
from sqlalchemy import event

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()
```