Flask SQL, alembic and SQlite: how to avoid delete object when is referenced (Foreign Key)
Given 2 tables: transactions and categories.
Transactions contains a FK category_id with the ID of assigned category.
I want to not allow delete categories referenced by transactions. I mean: if there is one transaction with category_id 3, for example, I want to get an error from DB if delete the categry with ID 3. Like other db engines oracle, mysql...
But, in my case, I'm able to delete it. The transaction still containing the categoty_exists, but that ID not exists on categories tables.
As mentioned in the title, I am using flask sql to create my models and alembic to database migrations with a sqlite database.
My sqlalchemy models:
class TransactionModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'transactions'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    date = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    amount = db.Column(db.Numeric(precision=10, scale=2), nullable=False)
    concept = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False)
    category_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('categories.id', ondelete='RESTRICT'), nullable=True)
    category = db.relationship("CategoryModel")

class CategoryModel(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'categories'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(24), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(128), nullable=False)

With that models, there is the migration scripts generated:
def upgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.create_table('categories',
                    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('name', sa.String(length=24), nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('description', sa.String(length=128), nullable=False),
                    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
                    )
    op.create_table('transactions',
                    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), autoincrement=True, nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('date', sa.Date(), nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('amount', sa.Numeric(precision=10, scale=2), nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('concept', sa.String(length=100), nullable=False),
                    sa.Column('category_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=True),
                    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['category_id'], ['categories.id'], ondelete='RESTRICT'),
                    sa.PrimaryKeyConstraint('id')
                    )
    # ### end Alembic commands ###


def downgrade():
    # ### commands auto generated by Alembic - please adjust! ###
    op.drop_table('transactions')
    op.drop_table('categories')
    # ### end Alembic commands ###

When I execute the migration, these are the generated tables:
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

CREATE TABLE transactions (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL, 
    date DATE NOT NULL, 
    amount NUMERIC(10, 2) NOT NULL, 
    concept VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    category_id INTEGER, 
    PRIMARY KEY (id), 
    FOREIGN KEY(category_id) REFERENCES categories (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
)

The behavior is so extrange:
Given 2 categories (ids 1 and 2), and 2 transactions. Transaction 1 with category_id=1 and transaction 2 with category 2. If I delete category 2, transaction 2 still with category_id=2. Then, if I create a new category, it is not taking new ID 3, is getting ID 2 because there is not category 2. Result? Now, the transaction 2 appears with category 3 because the newest category 3 is the category with the "old" id 2.
But, given the same example (2 categories, 2 transactions) if I delete category 1, because category 2 existing, the new category no is with ID 3.
My goals:

Prevent delete category 1 and 2 because they are referenced on table transactions. Only be able to delete a category if is not referenced on any table.
Prevent the reutilization of old IDs. If I delete category 2, the ID 2 will not be used never, like sequences on oracle for exapmle.

Yes, I can do it on my application logic. But I want to get it working well in database too in order to reduce human errors when use directly the database queries.
EDIT:
I have created manual migration with this:
def upgrade():
    op.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON")

And still not working.
Checking database, I noticed that foreigns_keys still not enabled (I don't know why if the migration file was executed correctly...)
But then, I have executed the "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON" directly on database and now foreign_keys appears as 1 but still working with the same behavior.
Based on: https://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html

possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64811882/2144390

Yeah, probably. But, what is the solution?

I mean, how can I execute "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON" using alembic script?

I tried it. Not working.

PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON is not a persistent database setting, so adding that to your Alembic migration script won't help you. You need to send that statement every time you connect to the database, as described in the docs here
